# Picard Iteration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

[image]

For part b) I understand how to get to $z_1=    \begin{pmatrix} 
        t \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \quad$and because $z=    \begin{pmatrix} 
        x \\
        p \\
        \end{pmatrix} \quad$ when I last attempted this question I automatically wrote down  $x_1=t$. However I don't rigorously understand why we can do this.

i.e Why is $z_1=    \begin{pmatrix} 
        x_1 \\
        p_1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} $?

Comment: What else can you imagine it to be? It is quite natural to call the $x$ component of the first iterate $x_1$.